# LWUIT IO ConnectionRequest: POST request, how to get the Response's Headers?

Tags: web-services, rest, java-me, lwuit, midp

I send POST request to create some data resource on server. I get Response Code 201 - all is OK. But I also need to get 2 headers from the response. Those headers contain attributes of the created resource. I did not find the way how to do it using ConnectionRequest's API.

The class has readHeaders(connection) and getHeader(connection) protected methods. But I could not use them when I got the response - got an exception.

My code example is shown below:

```java
ConnectionRequest reqresp = new ConnectionRequest () {
    protected  void buildRequestBody (java.io.OutputStream os) {
    Logger.inst ().write ("buildRequestBody");
        final String body = "Dummy Request Body"; // necessary for my request
        try {
            os.write (body.getBytes () );
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            final String errMsg = ex.toString ();
            Logger.inst ().write (errMsg);
            throw new RuntimeException (errMsg);
        }
    }

    protected void readResponse (InputStream input) throws IOException  {
        // Actually this method will not be called.
        Logger.inst ().write ("readResponse");
        String respText;
        try {
            respText = Util.readToString (input);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            final String errMsg = ex.toString ();
            Logger.inst ().write (errMsg);
            throw new RuntimeException (errMsg);
        }
        Logger.inst ().write (respText);
    }
};
reqresp.setUrl ("MY SERVER URL");
reqresp.setPriority (ConnectionRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH);
reqresp.setPost (true);
reqresp.addRequestHeader ("header1", "val1");
reqresp.addRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/json");
reqresp.addResponseCodeListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
            Logger.inst ().write ("ResponseCodeListener:");
            Logger.inst ().write (ae.toString () );
            if (ae instanceof NetworkEvent) {
                NetworkEvent evt = (NetworkEvent)ae;
                Logger.inst ().write ("message: " + evt.getMessage () );
                Logger.inst ().write ("response code: " + evt.getResponseCode () );
            }
        }
    });
reqresp.addResponseListener (
    new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
            Logger.inst ().write ("ResponseCodeListener:");
            Logger.inst ().write (ae.toString () );
            if (ae instanceof NetworkEvent) {
                NetworkEvent evt = (NetworkEvent)ae;
                Logger.inst ().write ("message: " + evt.getMessage () );
                Logger.inst ().write ("response code: " + evt.getResponseCode () );
            }
        }
    }
);

NetworkManager.getInstance ().addToQueue (reqresp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not perform the task using the LWUIT's IO. But I did it easily using the MIDP's HTTPConnection and met no problems.

One small comment about the MIDP's HTTPConnection API. It's synchronous. So, I did not want to use it in the main GUI thread. Moreover, the API is low-level. So, I had to implement some kind of wrapper to hide the details and to execute HTTP request asynchronously in a separate thread.

Now one comment about the LWUIT's IO ConnectionRequest class. I found it programmer-unfriendly. It represents both a request and response. So, it's not clear what the methods are related to the request and what to the response.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in the `ConnectionRequest`:

```
protected void readHeaders(Object connection) throws IOException {
    String val = getHeader(connection, "MyHeaderName");
}
```

Comment: Already tried - that method was not called. I did't know why. I also tried to override getHeader (). The same - was not called. I overrode initConnection (connection) and it was called. Cool! I tried to store the passed connection in it and use it later in the response code listener, but got the exception (the connection is already closed).

Comment: If I call readHeaders() in initConnection() after the calling the base implementation, then I got an exception later when buildRequestBody() method is called (err msg is something like "impossible to modify a request which has already be started").

Comment: Check the signature of the method. If the response you got is 2xx it must be invoked (look at the code), your other workaround approaches don't fit well into the lifecycle.

Comment: Just checked the signature - it's correct. The returned response code is 201 (CREATED). The readHeaders() method is not called. BTW, readResponse() isn't called also.

Comment: Shai, 1 comment about ConnectionRequest class. IMHO, it is difficult to use it since it represents both a request and response (couples them). It's not clear what methods are related to request and what to response. ...to many methods in 1 place...

Comment: 2 more comments: 1. Why there are no any public methods for getting response headers after request is complete (or listener)? 2. You told that readHeaders() might be called if response code was 2xx. What if response code is out of that range? I may also need response headers in that case. For example, for correct interpretation of response body. Or my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: If your response code is 3xx then you are implicitly redirected, if its 4xx its an error and you can get the error message. I don't see the use case for accessing a header otherwise. The methods aren't public because they are only usable for a short amount of time before the connection is closed so you must override readHeaders(). I have no idea why its not working for you, I suggest you just get the code from SVN and place a breakpoint to see what is happening. Its really easy to do that.